# FluentNhibernate .CheckReference is failing

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

```
public class WorldEntity
{
    public WorldEntity()
    {
        Scenes = new List<SceneEntity>();
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Picture { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SceneEntity> Scenes { get; set; }

}

public class WorldMap : ClassMap<WorldEntity>
{
    public WorldMap()
    {
        Table("Worlds");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Picture);
        HasMany(x => x.Scenes).KeyColumn("Id");
    }
}

public class SceneEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Image { get; set; }
        //public virtual int WorldId { get; set; }
        public virtual WorldEntity World { get; set; }
        public virtual short NoExits { get; set; }
        public virtual string AnimatedIntroPath { get; set; }
    }

    public class SceneMap: ClassMap<SceneEntity>
    {
        public SceneMap()
        {
            Table("Scenes");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Name);
            Map(x => x.Image);
            Map(x => x.NoExits);
            Map(x => x.AnimatedIntroPath);
            //Map(x => x.WorldId).Not.Nullable();
            References(wrd => wrd.World, "WorldId");
        }
    }

[Test]
     new PersistenceSpecification<SceneEntity>(Session)
            .CheckProperty(x => x.Name, "Scene Name")
            .CheckProperty(x => x.Image, "path to image")
            //.CheckProperty(x=>x.WorldId,aa.Id)
            .CheckReference(x => x.World,aa )
            .VerifyTheMappings();
```

after running the test I am getting this error:

System.ApplicationException : For property 'World' expected same element, but got different element of type 'TwitQuestNet.DataDefinitions.OrmConfig.Entities.WorldEntity'.
Tip: override ToString() on the type to find out the difference.
   at FluentNHibernate.Testing.Values.Property`2.CheckValue(Object target)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at FluentNHibernate.Testing.PersistenceSpecification`1.VerifyTheMappings(T first)
   at TwitQuestNet.Test.EntityMapTests.SceneTest.scene_map_succsess() in SceneTest.cs: line 23

what I am doing wrong here ? as I am stuck for nearly a day :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. I had to add EqualityComparer() the the test will pass